# What's the point of Euler's number in exponents?

Tags: exponential-function

I want to know why we use $(1+e^{\text{something}})^{-1}$ for artificial intelligence. I know $e$ is just $2.7$.

So what? Why $2.7$ and not $3$?

Does it have a special property?

Comment: ${d\over dt}(e^t)=e^t$.

Comment: So if I want to see the rate of my growth, it is already the growth itsel...f??

Comment: That's so cool!

Comment: How do I precisely calculate E? Can I divide something by something to get it?

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm going to write a for loop to get the letter e for my neural network. 1/1 + 1/2+ 1/3+ 1/4 and so on

Comment: Your for loop will want to be adding: $1/1+1/2+1/6+1/24+1/120+1/720+1/5040+1/40320+...$

Comment: @NicholasStull Avoid using the comments section as a chat. There's a chat for that.

Comment: I already asked this in chat!

Comment: $e=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+/n)^n$, and that is an increasing sequence, so just plug a big $n$ to get an approximation.

Comment: Why 2.7 and not 3 is a deep question. I also wonder why $\pi$ is 3.14 but not just 3. The world will be much simpler in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see $e$ as the unique real number such that
$$
\ln (e)=1
$$ giving
$$
e=2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709370\ldots.
$$ One may prove that
$$
\ln(e^x)=x, \quad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$$$
e^{\ln (x)}=x, \quad x \in (0,\infty),
$$$$
\frac{d}{dx}e^x =e^x \quad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$ $$
e^x =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\quad x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: This doesn't answer the "why $e$ and not $3$?"

Comment: It does. We have $\ln 3=1.09\ldots>1$, thus $3$ can't be $e$.

Comment: hahaha YoTengoUnLCD is such a smart ass... I love this answer @Olivier Oloa!! I'm going to keep playing with this to compute e out manually in my network

Comment: That last part looks familiar. I wonder why they use n factorial in the bottom?

Comment: I suppose you should add that $\ln x := \int_1^x t^{-1}\, \mathrm{d}t$ (else, if you use the more usual definition, $\ln x = \exp^{-1}$, this is rather circular).

Comment: @tylerl-uxai Excuse me?

Comment: Yo are you trying to boss people around who are trying to learn?

Comment: @tylerl-uxai What? I don't see where you got that from.

Comment: Please keep the discussion clean.

Comment: @tylerl-uxai why the factorial in the bottom of $e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ follows either from the definition of $e^x$ or from [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem) (depending on how you originally define $e$).  Ahlfors defines $e^z$ as the unique solution to the differential equation $f'(z)=f(z)$ with the initial value $f(0)=1$ from which the result follows almost immediately.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'm really sorry for saying the a word!

Comment: @JMoravitz I hope it's ok I keep asking a lot of questions on this stack overflow. I just am really curious. Here's the formula you gave plus the neural network "activation function". Maybe you can help me understand why we don't just use a huge formula like the n!. It seems like n! will be perfect for computation when we start using atoms instead of electrons. And at that point we'll want to be precise with math... instead of using 2.7 we'll want to plug in the precise derivative of euler's number, which is what I'm aiming for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753592/how-does-this-work

Comment: sorry but I don't think you have the level yet for understanding neural networks, you should try to study first matrices (linear algebra), calculus (derivatives integrals), etc...

Comment: and you should go on stackoverflow instead, read the already answered questions, they will tell you what you need to learn for understanding machine learning when you are not a "mathematician".

Comment: Wow, you actually have more digits of $e$ in this question than I have memorized.  :D

Answer (score 2):

The number $e^{\text{something}}$ can always be written as $3^{\text{something else}}$, where “something” and “something else” only differ by a constant factor ($\ln(3)$, to be precise). So it doesn't really matter what base you use for your exponentials. It's just that $e^x$ is much more convenient when computing derivatives, for example. And almost all programming languages already have a function for computing $e^x$, typically called **exp(x)**, so don't write your own implementation!

Comment: Too late! I'm debugging it now. I wrote my own Euler's number script and my own factorial loop (that I don't think has been written the way I did). So I have literally made the whole process of AI transparent for math geeks like myself :D